User API-key authentication in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
The scenario:

A web application built using latest asp.net core
Uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity for cookie-based authentication

Users can log in with username/password
Users can log in with external login providers
Usernames/passwords/external login info is stored in database using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore



Issue/question:

I would like to add API key authentication to the application, with users being able to create API keys and then use the keys to do API calls from Excel, Power BI etc.
When a request with a API key header comes to the application, the application should look up the API key and find the user accociated with the key.
The request handling should then continue as normal, with HttpContext.User set up correctly.
Can API key authentication be handled by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity? Is this scenario supported out-of-the box?


Raw API key authentication (as in a custom header or query param) is considered a custom authentication flow and you need to implement it yourself. But if you use OAuth machine-to-machine flow (aka client credentials), then the framework has built-in support for it.

You should implement jwt bearer authentication too, and implement some rest API endpoints to handle login flow. In your case instead of username and password you should login the excel application with the associated key.
